# Spark dependencies configuration for streaming from Twitter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter, sbt

I am trying to run a Spark application with a Twitter streaming. However, I constantly experiencing problems with dependencies.
When I use org.apache.bahir spark-streaming-twitter dependency I get such an error:

```
module not found: org.apache.bahir#spark-streaming-twitter;2.0.0
```

Here is the corresponding build.sbt file:

```
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.3.0",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "4.0.6"
)
```

But when I use older streaming dependency I get `ClassNotFoundException: : org.apache.spark.Logging` error.
Here is the corresponding build.sbt:

```
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.3.0",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "4.0.6",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.6.3"
)
```

In order to run my application, I run `sbt clean and package` commands.
So what dependencies should I use and how to configure them to run my application?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter backend has been removed from Spark with 2.0 release and version of bahir you declared doesn't match Spark version. Finally bahir Twitter already comes with `twitter4j-stream` dependency (4.0.4 at this moment). Use:

```
val sparkVersion = "2.3.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion
)
```

Comment: If you don't want to build Bahir for 2.3 yourself, you have to downgrade __all__ dependencies to 2.2. You cannot mix between major versions.

Comment: Looks like you didn't use correct build definition. Message shows that your attempt doesn't include Scala version. There is a difference between `%%` and `%` (you need `org.apache.spark#spark-launcher_2.11;2.2.0`  not `org.apache.bahir#spark-streaming-twitter;2.2.0`)